# Using Sublime Text 2 Build System with SQL*Plus and Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, sublimetext2, sqlplus, sublimetext

I'm trying to setup [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) so that I can code my Oracle packages, triggers, functions, etc.  I have the build system compiling my code just fine.  Now I'm working on trying to get Sublime Text to take me to the exact line/column position when an error happens.  To do this you have to use the `file_regex` option **[documented here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)**.

> The file_regex option uses a Perl-style regular expression to capture
>   up to four fields of error information from the build program’s
>   output, namely: filename, line number, column number and error
>   message. Use groups in the pattern to capture this information. The
>   filename field and the line number field are required.

My problem seems to be `filename`, which is the first required thing.  **My question is at the very bottom** but let me show you how everything is setup because others may find this useful.

Here is my build system (`compileSql.sublime-build`)...

```
{
    "cmd": ["c:\\projectX\\compileSql.bat", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)"
}
```

Here is `compileSql.bat`.  All this does is it makes a new file called `runFile.txt` which contains the file I'm currently working on in Sublime text, except it starts the file off with `set defined off;`, then my code, then ends with `show errors;`  It then logs in and compiles the package (trigger, function, whatever)...

```
@echo set define off; > c:\projectX\runFile.txt
type %1 >> c:\projectX\runFile.txt
@echo show errors; >> c:\projectX\runFile.txt
sqlplus -s {user}/{pwd}@{database} @c:\projectX\runFile.txt
```

So all I have to do is press <kbd>F7</kbd> and it compiles for me...
[image]

But when I get an error, this is the result...
[image]

When I click on the error is doesn't take me to that line number.  Instead it opens a file called `8`.  So back up to my build system, I know the problem is with this: `"file_regex": "^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)"`.  [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) requires the first matched pattern to be the file.  That's the part I'm not grasping, why does it need to know that?  It's the file I'm working on, the one I just pressed <kbd>F7</kbd> for.  So something needs to come before the `([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)` in the regular expression, I don't know what to put in there.